# Text in mat-raised-button is invisible within mat-toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material2

This simple code:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button mat-raised-button>Basic</button>
</mat-toolbar>
<button mat-raised-button>Basic</button>
```

Give me this result : [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeZEr.png)

It seems that it is a know bug : https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4614

I need a clean workaround, can someone help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: This is a known issue. Do you want the button to be white inside the toolbar?

Comment: I am using a custom theme and I don't have this problem. Also, what's your angular material version ?

Comment: Nope, I would like the text color to remain unchanged (the basic text-color of the theme), if possible without having to hard code a dirty black text color in the component's scss.

Comment: i dkon't know which version i am using.
I have this dependency in my package.json : "@angular/material": "^5.0.2"

Answer (score 0):

i wrote my theme in /style.scss.
The color i chose for my primary palette influence the reproductability of the bug.

For exemple, this doesn't works :

```
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);
```

But this works :

```
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-green);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);
```

I just changed $mat-indigo to $mat-green and now my text is visible
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS5mp.png)

What's going on ?